# Text output starts with new line before every comma appearance

Tags: r, replace

I want to get the output in such a way that new line should start before every comma after tab indent.

**Desired output**:

```
function (formula
    , data
    , subset)
```

from `function (formula, data, subset)`. My MWE is

```
Txt <- "function (formula, data, subset)"
gsub(pattern=",", replacement=",\n\tab", x=Txt)
```

Comment: Nine seconds too late, story of my life.. Also note that the tab delimiter is `\t` not `\tab`

Comment: @rawr We all know the feeling, trust me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression pattern is almost correct, you just need the magical incantation for a tab stop, which is `\t`.

Try this:

```
cat(gsub(pattern=",", replacement="\n\t,", x=Txt))

function (formula
    , data
    , subset)
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Andrie for your nice answer. How can I use this command to get arguments of R functions like this: `cat(gsub(pattern=",", replacement="\n\t,", x=args(lm)))`.

Comment: @MYaseen208 use `formals(lm)` instead.

Comment: `formals(lm)` is nor working as desired. But this is much close to required output `cat(gsub(pattern=",", replacement="\n\t,", x=formatR:::usage(lm)))`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives much close to required output

```
cat(gsub(pattern=",", replacement="\n\t,", x=formatR:::usage(lm)))

lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", model = TRUE,
    x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL,
    offset, ...)
lm(formula
    , data
    , subset
    , weights
    , na.action
    , method = "qr"
    , model = TRUE
    ,
    x = FALSE
    , y = FALSE
    , qr = TRUE
    , singular.ok = TRUE
    , contrasts = NULL
    ,
    offset
    , ...)
```